"to do a DNA test" VS "to get a DNA test" VS "to have a DNA test"

"It only took that show to spur Tina to do her DNA test. It's thanks to them, to be honest." BBC - DNA test

Unlike doing a test at school, "to do a DNA test" in this sentence reminded of other verbs (get/have) used with medical tests. Although they all seem all right to me, I wonder whether both "get" and "have" could be used in place of one another:
- to get a DNA test,
- to have a DNA test.
- to do a DNA test.

There's a causative sense here.  The nonfinite clause
to do a DNA test means to get a DNA test done. The test will be done by others engaged by Tina.
Yes,

to get (or have) a DNA test

is possible.  We can also use the causative form to 'get' (or 'have') a DNA test done.

I wondered whether there was a distinction between 'doing' a self-administered test (you take a sample and send it away for analysis) and 'getting' it done by a technician?

We've already reached the point where someone can be DNA-tested as a "compound verb" (hyphenated or not, it's all the same in speech). I seriously doubt many if any native speakers would think any of the possible phrasings makes it more likely the speaker / writer posted off his own swab / sample for analysis, as opposed to having a medical professional take the sample. And who does the actual test at home?
